# Does this definition of a primitive polynomial make sense?

Tags: coding-theory

I have this question in a past exam paper.

Let $F_p$ be the field of integers modulo prime $p$.

I have the question

> What is meant by saying $f$ is primitive?

This is the solution I have.

> If deg$f=h$ and $f(\alpha)=0$ for $\alpha \in F_p h$ then $f$ is
>   primitive if the order of $\alpha$ is $p^h -1$.

What is $p^h$?

Comment: It's the usual $h$th power of $p$, as a natural number.

Comment: That's just the *definition* of a primitive polynomial. Provided that you include the requirement that $f$ must be irreducible over the prime field.